# Dialogflow Oauth Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to connect to "dialogflow" via API, however when I use Oauth it asks for a google user authentication, is there any method to avoid web verification?

Comment: so, you want to use OAuth without verification ... do you leave your car unlocked with the keys in the ignition but put up a sign that says "please don't steal my car" - or did I miss the premise of your question?

Comment: my problem is that the conection is made via backend so no client can do manually the Oauth2 panel verification